# Validation against DTD with lxml in python is disturbed by xmlns

Tags: python, validation, lxml

I'm trying to validate an XML document in Python using lxml.

DTD validation will treat the presence of xmlns namespaces as errors.

This example script

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

dtd = etree.DTD(StringIO("<!ELEMENT a EMPTY>"))
root = etree.XML("<a></a>")
print(dtd.validate(root))
root = etree.XML('<a xmlns:sru="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/"></a>')
print(dtd.validate(root))
print dtd.error_log
```

yields

```
True
False
<string>:1:0:ERROR:VALID:DTD_UNKNOWN_ATTRIBUTE: No declaration for attribute xmlns:sru of element a
```

How can I have lxml validate my document against a DTD without complaining about xml namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the xmlns:sru attribute for the a element in your DTD. It currently doesn't have one.

```
<!ELEMENT a EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST a xmlns:sru CDATA #IMPLIED>
```

This defines an optional CDATA attribute for xmlns:sru on element a.

Comment: Sounds fair. I thought that `xmlns:foo` attributes were "automatically" always allowed, but I see now it is explicitly mentioned in http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html. Thanks.

Comment: no problem, been wanting to try out lxml for a while. best of luck